# Get history record which was popped on onpopstate event

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have a listener to `onpopstate` event. I want to get record of history which was popped without travelling in history. I could do `history.forward()` and get state, but that will cause side-effects I don't want to see.

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
    prevHistoryRecord = // How to get it without history.forward()
});
```

Comment: why not simply use event.state or history.state?

Comment: Because event state and history state stores current state and not the state which was popped

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to access a state added/modified by a framework or other part of your application. In that case, you can overwrite history functions and listen, store state changes in an object, which is accessible to you

```js
const historyState = []
const fn = history.pushState.bind(history)
history.pushState = function() {
  console.log('Push state', arguments)
  historyState.push({ args: arguments })
  fn.apply(history, arguments)
}
history.pushState('arg1', 'arg2')
```

You should overwrite history object before it has been used in your case. So, you will have access to a copy of history state. 
It might also be accessible in History as well but I have no idea if you can reach it.

Comment: I don't like the idea of modifying global objects and their methods because it can decrease isolation and cause unpredictable behaviour in the future (for example somebody decided to modify pushState in other repo which I import and he will not have any idea that he will break my app and I will not be able to find what's wrong)

Comment: Well, the api doesn't give state object. I don't think you can access it other way. This is a safe side effect but I agree it's not the prettiest solution